# Identifying GTK 3 Widget / Property

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, gtk3

I am attempting to modify the Paper gtk 3 theme to take out some undesirable features. Specifically, certain buttons have this pesky outline in the bottom right corner when hovered on or clicked. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMKtw.png

This effect also appears on the toolbar buttons in Chrome.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOwBh.png

Ideally, I would like to remove this behavior and replace it with something a bit more desirable. I'm new to GTK, but I started by diving into the CSS for the theme. Unfortunately, there are 56 different CSS widget files and I have no clue what the name of this type of widget or the behavior might be.

I decided to grep for :hover and started commenting out blocks to see if I could get the behavior to go away. After commenting out about twenty blocks, I began to realize that something might be wrong. Is it possible that the theme simply did not implement behavior for this widget and the outline is default GTK behavior?

So, my question is threefold:

1. What are the names of the indicated widgets in my images above?
2. What is a possible name for the css property causing the outline behavior?
3. Does GTK define default behavior for widgets without a css implementation and, if so, could that be happening here?

Comment: I don't see the outline in your Chrome image, but your LibreOffice image image seems to show the default :hover behavior, yes. I wouldn't know beyond that.